# Sum outputs from atoi

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to learn C++14 (with a "modern"/non-C style). I am trying to sum the digits in a string, for the digits that are equal to the next digit (or the first digit, if at the end of the string). I solved it in Python, but in C++14, I get unexpected output.

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

using sum_t =  uint64_t; // int; // unsigned long long;

// sum_digits sums the digits in the given std::string and returns an integer of type sum_t
sum_t sum_digits(std::string digits) {
    sum_t total = 0;
    for (const auto &digit : digits) {
        total += atoi(new char(digit));
        cout << "sum this far: " << total << endl;
    }
    return total;
}

// return the last char
// returns ' ' if given an empty string
char last(std::string digits) {
    auto dl = digits.length();
    if (dl < 1) {
        return ' ';
    }
    return digits.at(dl - 1);
}

// sum_equal_digits returns a sum of the digits that are equal to the next one
sum_t sum_equal_digits(std::string digits) {
    auto equal_digits = ""s; // a list of equal digits, as std::string
    auto prev_digit = last(digits); // start with the last digit, since the digit list is supposed to be circular
    for (const auto &digit : digits) {
        if (digit == prev_digit) {
            equal_digits += digit;
        }
        prev_digit = digit;
    }
    return sum_digits(equal_digits);
}

void equal(sum_t a, sum_t b) {
    if (a == b) {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "NO" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main() {
    equal(sum_equal_digits("1122"s), 3);
    equal(sum_equal_digits("1111"s), 4);
    equal(sum_equal_digits("1234"s), 0);
    equal(sum_equal_digits("91212129"s), 9);
    equal(sum_equal_digits("823936645345581272695677318513459491834641129844393742672553544439126314399846773234845535593355348931499496184839582118817689171948635864427852215325421433717458975771369522138766248225963242168658975326354785415252974294317138511141826226866364555761117178764543435899886711426319675443679829181257496966219435831621565519667989898725836639626681645821714861443141893427672384716732765884844772433374798185955741311116365899659833634237938878181367317218635539667357364295754744829595842962773524584225427969467467611641591834876769829719248136613147351298534885563144114336211961674392912181735773851634298227454157885241769156811787611897349965331474217223461176896643242975397227859696554492996937235423272549348349528559432214521551656971136859972232854126262349381254424597348874447736545722261957871275935756764184378994167427983811716675476257858556464755677478725146588747147857375293675711575747132471727933773512571368467386151966568598964631331428869762151853634362356935751298121849281442128796517663482391226174256395515166361514442624944181255952124524815268864131969151433888721213595267927325759562132732586252438456569556992685896517565257787464673718221817783929691626876446423134331749327322367571432532857235214364221471769481667118117729326429556357572421333798517168997863151927281418238491791975399357393494751913155219862399959646993428921878798119215675548847845477994836744929918954159722827194721564121532315459611433157384994543332773796862165243183378464731546787498174844781781139571984272235872866886275879944921329959736315296733981313643956576956851762149275521949177991988236529475373595217665112434727744235789852852765675189342753695377219374791548554786671473733124951946779531847479755363363288448281622183736545494372344785112312749694167483996738384351293899149136857728545977442763489799693492319549773328626918874718387697878235744154491677922317518952687439655962477734559232755624943644966227973617788182213621899579391324399386146423427262874437992579573858589183571854577861459758534348533553925167947139351819511798829977371215856637215221838924612644785498936263849489519896548811254628976642391428413984281758771868781714266261781359762798"), 1144);
    return 0;
}
```

The last two lines of the output are:

```
sum this far: 18446744073627459815
NO
```

But I was expecting:

```
sum this far: 1144                                                                                
YES
```

I compiled the program with:

```
g++ -O2 -std=c++14 -Wfatal-errors -pedantic -Wall main.cpp -o main
```

I also tried `using sum_t = int;` and `using sum_t = uint64_t;`.

How can the program be corrected?

Comment: Is there a reason why your last test case is the only one not having the form "<number as a string>"**s** ?

Comment: `atoi(new char(digit))` <= what.

Comment: No, good catch @vonludi. It seems like the string is converted to std::string when it's being passed to a function with that as the argument type?

Comment: @Alexander that's because `std::string` has an [implicit conversion constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (#4). This means it can be directly constructed from a `char const *` such as the pointer decayed from a string literal :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addtion to Mr1Penguin's answer, which is right for atoi; one could avoid the whole atoi hastle with

```
sum_t sum_digits(std::string digits) {
    sum_t total = 0;
    for (const auto &digit : digits)
        total += digit - '0'
    return total;
}
```

but it won't have quite the same protection against non numeric characters.

Comment: As an additional performance improvement (although at higher risk of overflow) you could do `total += digit` and then `return total - '0' * digits.length()` but you're unlikely to ever notice the difference

Comment: Thank you! This made the program work as expected. I'm still mystified by `atoi`, though. :)

Comment: @Alexander atoi takes a null terminated string.  You were passing it a single character, meaning it would look at the next piece of random memory, and the next, until it hit a 0; and then attempt to convert that to a number.  The answer from penguin created an array of chars, the last being a 0 and never changed;  This meant that atoi would always just look at the first char, and return the int value of it.

Answer (score 3):

atoi takes argument as null-terminated string.

So you should make something like:

```
sum_t sum_digits(std::string digits) {
    sum_t total = 0;
    char tmp[2] = { 0 };
    for (const auto &digit : digits) {
    tmp[0] = digit;
    total += atoi(tmp);
        cout << "sum this far: " << total << endl;
    }
    return total;
}
```

P.S.

`new` without `delete` leads to memory leaks (`atoi(new char(digit))`).

Comment: Note, instead of using atoi() for this case. One can just do `total += digit - '0'`

Answer (score 1):

Some additional annotations: The function `atoi()` **is** a C-style function, which requires a 0-terminated C-style string (see other comments). Also the header `stdlib.h` is a C-Header. If you write C++-Code you should use `#include <cstdlib>` instead. You can also use `std::stoi()` defined in `#include <string>`, but it does not performs good, because it has to construct a string object from the character.